# Alternative to deployJava.runApplet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I want to load my `applet` in a `HTML` page using `javascript`, so I tried to load it with `deployJava` as:

```
<script>

    var attributes = {
        id:         "myApplet",
        code:       "mycode",
        archive:    "myApplet.jar, lib/jna.jar, lib/junit-4.10.jar, lib/native.bat",
        width:      30,
        height:     30
    };
    var parameters = {jnlp_href:"launch.jnlp"}; <!-- Applet Parameters -->
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == false) 
    { 
        alert("No Java or wrong version"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        alert("Java found"); 
    }
    var version = "1.6"; <!-- Required Java Version -->
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

but I don't want to use `deployJava` class. Is there any alternative for loading `applet` in javascript?

Comment: there is a pulpcore framework to load applets in javascript this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146725/pulpcore-and-javascript-to-java-applet-communication

Comment: I did not find an alternative. I ended up adding the generated `applet` tag and threw away depoyJava.js completely as the browser will hint the user to install the plugin anyways.